# Create a QVariant from a metatype id

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

Is there anyway to create a QVariant from a metatype id ?

For example :

```
int id = qRegisterMetaType<MyStruct>();
QVariant myVariant = QVariant::fromMetaType(id);
```

So myVariant is now a QVariant containing a default-constructed value of "MyStruct".

I didn't find anyway to do this with the QVariant API, did I miss something, or is there any trick ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the `QVariant` [constructors](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#QVariant-2) does it:

```
QVariant::QVariant(int typeId, const void *copy)
```

Note that `copy` can be a `nullptr`. So, your code would be:

```
auto id = qRegisterMetaType<MyStruct>();
QVariant myVariant{id, nullptr};
```

Of course, if you have the type itself available, there's no point to using the metatype id, you should be using `fromValue`.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for it. I have the metatype id available, but not the type itself in this piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) is example how to do it:

Instead of `QVariant myVariant = QVariant::fromMetaType(id);` you can write:

```
MyStruct s;
QVariant var;
var.setValue(s);
```

Another option is `fromValue` (found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#fromValue)):

```
MyCustomStruct s;
QVariant var = QVariant::fromValue(s);
```